# How to pass null as values to any variable in cURL command or Browser command for REST ATG?

Tags: rest, curl, atg

First call:

```
curl -L -v \
     -c customer_cookies.txt \
     -b customer_cookies.txt \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d "{\"couponClaimCode\":\"0001\"}" \
"http://localhost:7103/rest/model/atg/commerce/promotion/CouponActor/claimCoupon"
```

Second call:

```
http://localhost:7103/rest/model/atg/commerce/promotion/CouponActor/claimCoupon?couponClaimCode=0001
```

Both calls are doing the same thing: passing coupon code. Suppose if i want to pass null as a value, then how should i do that?

Answer (score 4):

[JSON](http://json.org/) supports `null`. This

```
{"couponClaimCode": null}
```

is valid JSON. If the code that accepts the `POST` handles JSON correctly, this should work.

Passing a null value of `couponClaimCode` as a query param depends on what your backend understands. Would

```
?couponClaimCode=
```

be interpreted as the empty string `""` or as `null`? What about

```
?couponClaimCode=null
```

Is this the string `"null"` or `null`? You will have to look into your backend code to find out.

Comment: when i used {"couponClaimCode": null},i got the following response {"formError":true,"formExceptions":[{"localizedMessage":"No coupon could be found for the claim code.","errorCode":"noCouponFound"}]}.

Comment: As I said: you will have to understand your backend. I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

curl -L -v 
     -c customer_cookies.txt 
     -b customer_cookies.txt 
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
     -d "{\"couponClaimCode\":\"\"}" 
"http://localhost:7103/rest/model/atg/commerce/promotion/CouponActor/claimCoupon"